# error while building pjsip in linux

Tags: linux, sip, voip, pjsip

I am getting following error while building `pjsip` as mentioned in [**this link**](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf#SupportedTargets).

When I run the `make` command:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/errno.h:28:0,      
                 from ../include/pj/compat/socket.h:131,  
                 from ../src/pj/ioqueue_select.c:38:    
../src/pj/ioqueue_common_abs.c: In function ‘pj_ioqueue_recv’:  
../include/pj/compat/os_auto.h:149:31: error: ‘EAGAIN’ undeclared (first use in this function)   
 #define PJ_BLOCKING_ERROR_VAL EAGAIN
                               ^
```

**Edit:**

1. OS Name: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS && 64 bit
2. Build Command:

   ```
   cd pjproject-2.7.2/
   chmod 777 configure
   chmod 777 aconfigure
   ./configure  
   make dep  
   make
   ```

And downloaded the source code from [this link](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm)

Comment: Assume `$ svn co https://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk` ...  Please edit your question to include **1.** OS Name and version. **2.** The build command used, like `cd trunk/ && ./configure --option --option1 --option2 && make dep && make`

Comment: @KnudLarsen, Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: I have also tried to build from svn as you suggested but same result.

Comment: for which device you are trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64

`git clone https://github.com/svn2github/pjsip.git` ... or `pjproject-2.7.2.tar.bz2` : Both will build OK here, with gcc version 4.8 → `sudo apt install g++-4.8`

Build example, ref. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf

```
export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-memalign-hack
make dep && make
```

Interesting is that pjsip can be built with gcc, g++ v. 7.3 on an rpm based OS. But then again, the Ubuntu gcc´s have a very different patching.